# value change on Click Function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have single input fields namely `Estimate Property Tax`. This input field gets two type of value

1. First value is in %
2. Second value is in $

This is my code:

```
<td>Estimate Property Tax </td>
<td>
    <input name="propertytaxpc" type="text" size="8" maxlength="8" value="<?php echo $dproperty_tax; ?>" onChange="javascript:propertyTaxPcChanged(true)" /> %
</td>
<td>Or $

    <input name="propertytaxamt" type="text" size="8" maxlength="8" onChange="javascript:propertyTaxAmountChanged(true)" />
</td>
<td>
```

This code is an OLD UI. Old UI have separate input fields for % and $. Now I have designed to change two input fields change into a single input field. I have set % and $ icon .Now I get % as default value . I need to pass $ value when user change icon from % to $. My new code

```
<div class="col-md-4 padding-rht bdy">
    <label id="lblEstimatePropertyTax" class="pull-left" style="font-weight: 600">
        Estimate Property Tax</label>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3 padding-rht">
    <input name="propertytaxpc" class="txt" type="text" size="8" maxlength="8" value="<?php echo $dproperty_tax;?>" onChange="javascript:propertyTaxPcChanged(true)" />


</div>

<div class="col-md-1 padding-lft">
    <img src="Content/Images/percent.png" onclick="changeColor(event,this.src)" style="cursor:pointer" />
</div>
```

The single Input id I want pass two value % and $ .I have already created Icon change function script

```
 function changeColor(event, _src) {
        var fname = _src;
        var ImageName = fname.substring(fname.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        //alert(ImageName);
        if (ImageName == "percent.png") {
            $(event.target).attr("src", "Content/Images/RedDoller.png");
            document.querySelector('input[name=propertytaxpc]').value();
        }
        else {
            $(event.target).attr("src", "Content/Images/percent.png");
            document.querySelector('input[name=propertytaxamt]').value();
       }
    }
```

How to pass two value from a single input fields? Now icon only change?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
onclick="changeColor(event,this.src, document.querySelector('input[name=propertytaxpc]').value,document.querySelector('input[name=propertytaxamt]').value)"
```

Comment: not Working i have updated my script please take look what mistake in my script  please take look